# Откатился с 3.7 до 3.6 на питоне запускаю файл в pycharm

Tags: python

Я откатился с 3.7 до 3.6 запускаю файл и тут ошибка

```
D:\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/python
D:\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'D:/python'
```

не понимаю файл main.py расположен как раз в папке python почему не может найти?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1- ошибка не имеет отношения к версии Питона (поместите настоящую ошибку в заголовок) 2- `main.py` и `__main__.py` это разные имена (если папку дать, то Питон `__main__.py` из неё запускает)

Comment: Спасибо, то есть мне нужно переименовать файл в __main__.py ?

Comment: Я переименовал ошибка исчезла но в замен ещё 3 появилось)

Comment: Вот: D:\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:/python\__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

Comment: для новых ошибок, новый вопрос задайте